# Hide Highcharts labels on resize and enlarge the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a funnel chart that I need to extend through the whole container div when the page gets resized (and becomes thin)

I tried to programmatically hide the label on resize but the chart would still remain in a side of the div

https://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/9oh3ttss/7/

```
function toogle_chart_label(chart, series, show){
    var opt = chart.series[series].options;
    if(typeof show == 'undefined') {
        opt.dataLabels.enabled = !opt.dataLabels.enabled;
    } else {
        opt.dataLabels.enabled = show
    }
}

function funnel_labels_adjust(){
    if($('#container').width() < 300){
        toogle_chart_label(funnel_chart, 0, false)
    } else {
        toogle_chart_label(funnel_chart, 0, true)
    }
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
        funnel_labels_adjust()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Highcharts 5 there is a new property [responsive](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive). It allows you to specify the chart options which will be applied under some conditions.
In your case, you want to to disable data labels when the chart has width below 300.

```
responsive: {
        rules: [{
          condition: {
            maxWidth: 300
          },

          chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
              funnel: {
                dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/9oh3ttss/8/

If you dont want to use that feature, you need to use dynamic methods like [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update)

```
series[0].update({
  dataLabels: {enabled: false / true}
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. it correctly disables the labels but the chart does not re-scale to the full width of the div. the funnel still remains in the half left of the div

Comment: I missed that part. You have set marginRight property to 100, in responsive property set it to 0 and the funnel will scale to the full width of the container. https://jsfiddle.net/9oh3ttss/10/